# sending input from single spout to multiple bolts with Fields grouping in Apache Storm

Tags: apache-storm

```
builder.setSpout("spout", new TweetSpout());
builder.setBolt("bolt", new TweetCounter(), 2).fieldsGrouping("spout",
new Fields("field1"));
```

I have an input field "field1" added in fields grouping. By definition of fields grouping, all tweets with same "field1" should go to a single task of TweetCounter. The executors # set for TweetCounter bolt is 2.

However, if "field1" is the same in all the tuples of incoming stream, does this mean that even though I specified 2 executors for TweetCounter, the stream would only be sent to one of them and the other instance remains empty?

To go further with my particular use case, how can I use a single spout and send data to different bolts based on a particular value of an input field (field1)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems one way to solved this problem is to use [Direct grouping](http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.6/Concepts.html) where the source decides which component will receive the tuple. :

> This is a special kind of grouping. A stream grouped this way means that the producer of the tuple decides which task of the consumer will receive this tuple. Direct groupings can only be declared on streams that have been declared as direct streams. Tuples emitted to a direct stream must be emitted using one of the [emitDirect](javadocs/org/apache/storm/task/OutputCollector.html#emitDirect(int, int, java.util.List) methods. A bolt can get the task ids of its consumers by either using the provided TopologyContext or by keeping track of the output of the emit method in OutputCollector (which returns the task ids that the tuple was sent to).

You can see it's example uses [here](https://github.com/xetorthio/getting-started-with-storm/blob/master/ch03Topologies.asc):

```
 collector.emitDirect(getWordCountIndex(word),new Values(word));
```

where `getWordCountIndex` returns the index of the component where this tuple will be processes.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using `emitDirect` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53350141/8845188) is to implement your own stream grouping. The complexity is about the same, but it allows you to reuse grouping logic across multiple bolts.

For example, the shuffle grouping in Storm is implemented as a `CustomStreamGrouping` as follows:

```
public class ShuffleGrouping implements CustomStreamGrouping, Serializable {
    private ArrayList<List<Integer>> choices;
    private AtomicInteger current;

    @Override
    public void prepare(WorkerTopologyContext context, GlobalStreamId stream, List<Integer> targetTasks) {
        choices = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(targetTasks.size());
        for (Integer i : targetTasks) {
            choices.add(Arrays.asList(i));
        }
        current = new AtomicInteger(0);
        Collections.shuffle(choices, new Random());
    }

    @Override
    public List<Integer> chooseTasks(int taskId, List<Object> values) {
        int rightNow;
        int size = choices.size();
        while (true) {
            rightNow = current.incrementAndGet();
            if (rightNow < size) {
                return choices.get(rightNow);
            } else if (rightNow == size) {
                current.set(0);
                return choices.get(0);
            }
        } // race condition with another thread, and we lost. try again
    }
}
```

Storm will call `prepare` to tell you the task ids your grouping is responsible for, as well as some context on the topology. When Storm emits a tuple from a bolt/spout where you're using this grouping, Storm will call `chooseTasks` which lets you define which tasks the tuple should go to. You would then use the grouping when building your topology as shown:

```
TopologyBuilder tp = new TopologyBuilder();
tp.setSpout("spout", new MySpout(), 1);
tp.setBolt("bolt", new MyBolt())
  .customGrouping("spout", new ShuffleGrouping());
```

Be aware that groupings need to be `Serializable` and thread safe.